# Max connections

Tags: c#

What is max connections in a web.config?

If it is 40, does it mean only 40 users can be connected at a time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

MaxConnections specifies that at most 40 requests will be served at one time. It doesn't mean that only 40 users can sign in - just that if, say, 100 people request a page at the exact same moment, only 40 of them will be served one.